# Regular expression to remove special characters while retaining a valid email format

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation

I am using this in C#.  I start with an email-like string in this format:

```
employee[any characters]@company[any characters].com
```

I want to strip non-alphanumerics from the [any characters] pieces.

For example I want this `"employee1@2 r&a*d.m32@@company98 ';99..com"`

to become this `"employee12radm32@company9899.com"`

This expression simply takes all of the specials away, but I want to leave a single @ before company and a single . before com.  So I need the expression to ignore or mask out the employee, @company, and .com pieces... just not sure how to do that.

```
var regex = new Regex("[^0-9a-zA-Z]"); //whitelist the acceptables, remove all else.
```

Comment: The Regex expression itself would do what you need (beside it would remove the `@` and `.` as well) - it just depends on your programing language how you should use it. from `var` I assume javascript?

Comment: Why should it become `"employee12radm32@company9899.com"` but not `"employee1@2rad.m32company9899.com"`?

Comment: @Oriol the 2nd and 3rd line of OP should answer your question... that's always the starting format and what we want to do with it.  "@company" is always going to be the beginning of the email domain.

Comment: I updated OP to say this is C#.. also rephrased what I want it to do rather than implying what it "would do" (=

Comment: How does it come that you receive such a garbage as an input? What if you improve quality of the input instead of trying to fix it yourself?

Comment: What about `test@company.com@company.com`? Are you aware your current whitelist severely restricts normally valid emails and changes them to possibly someone elses email address (`jon-doe@company.com != jondoe@company.com`)?

Comment: @zerkms it's a very long horrible story...  but it's what I have to deal with.

Comment: @ErikPhilips yes I know this is all a terrible thing... but in this case I know the data won't have two "@company.com" .... that much I can be sure of.  The end result is something that just needs to pass as an email but it never actually gets used anywhere.

Comment: @chrismat I'm not judging, I don't know your business nor why decisions are made, only making sure that you are aware, in this case, specific side affects are possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
(?:\W)(?!company|com)
```

It will replace any special char, unless it is followed by `company` (so `@company` will remain) or `com` (so `.com` will remain):

```
employee1@2 r&a*d.m32@@company98 ';99..com
```

will become

```
employee12radm32@company9899.com
```

See: http://regex101.com/r/fY8jD7/2

Note that you need the `g` modifier to replace all occurences of such an unwanted character. 
this is default in C#, so you just can use a simple `Regex.Replace()`:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/iTeZ4F

---

Update:

ofc. the regex `(?:\W)(?!com)` would be enough - but it will still leave parts like `#com` or `~companion` since they match as well. So tis is *still* not a guarantee that the input - or lets say the conversion - is 100% valid. You should consider to simply throw a validation error, instead of trying to sanitize the input to match your needs.

Even if you would manage to handle *this* cases as well - what to do, if `@company` or `.com` appears two times?

Comment: Thanks dognose... at this time I know "@company" and .com don't appear twice... if the source data gets to that point, we will have a talk with those people (=  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your regex and replace it by

```
tmp = Regex.Replace(n, @"\W+", "");
```

where `\w` means all letters, digits, and underscores, and `\W` is the negated version of `\w`.
In general it is better to create a whitelist of allowed characters instead of trying to predict all not allowed symbols.

Comment: Is there a way to have the regex ignore the strings "employee", "@company" and ".com"?

Comment: It will also remove `@` symbol

Answer (score 0):

I would probably write something like:

(ignoring case sensitivity, if you need case sensitivity please comment).

[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JUXLPK)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var email = "employee1@2 r&a*d.m32@@company98 ';99..com";

        var result = GetValidEmail(email);

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }


    public static string GetValidEmail(string email)
    {
      var result = email.ToLower();

      // Does it contain everything we need?
      if (email.StartsWith("employee")
          && email.EndsWith(".com")
          && email.Contains("@company"))
      {
        // remove beginning and end.
        result = result.Substring(8, result.Length - 13);
        // remove @company
        var split = result.Split(new string[] { "@company" },
          StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        // validate we have more than two (you may not need this)
        if (split.Length != 2)
        {
          throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Email.");
        }

        // recreate valid email
        result = "employee"
          + new string (split[0].Where(c => char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)).ToArray())
          + "@company"
          + new string (split[1].Where(c => char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)).ToArray())
          + ".com";

      }
      else
      {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Email.");
      }

      return result;
    }
}
```

Result

> employee12radm32@company989.com

Comment: I was hoping to have to avoid something like this, but if regex can't handle this pattern, I guess it will have to do.  thx

Answer (score 0):

@dognose gave a great regex solution. I'll keep my answer here as a reference but I would go with his as it's much shorter/cleaner.

```
var companyName = "company";
var extension = "com";
var email = "employee1@2 r&a*d.m32@@company98 ';99..com";

var tempEmail = Regex.Replace(email, @"\W+", "");

var companyIndex = tempEmail.IndexOf(companyName);
var extIndex = tempEmail.LastIndexOf(extension);

var fullEmployeeName = tempEmail.Substring(0, companyIndex);
var fullCompanyName = tempEmail.Substring(companyIndex, extIndex - companyIndex);

var validEmail = fullEmployeeName + "@" + fullCompanyName + "." + extension;
```

Comment: Not really...  we know for sure the given format will be employee[any characters]@company[any characters].com.  We don't know what will be in [any characters], we just need to remove non-alphanumeric characters from the [any charactes] sections.

Comment: I think I fixed it to do what you're asking now.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is, though possible, a little bit complicated using one single regex pattern. You can break this scenario down into smaller steps. One way of doing it is to extract the `Username` and `Domain` groups (essentially what you described as `[any character]`), "fix" each group, and replace it with the original. Something like this:

```
// Original input to transform.
string input = @"employee1@2 r&a*d.m32@@company98 ';99..com";

// Regular expression to find and extract "Username" and "Domain" groups, if any.
var matchGroups = Regex.Match(input, @"employee(?<UsernameGroup>(.*))@company(?<DomainGroup>(.*)).com");

string validInput = input;

// Get the username group from the list of matches.
var usernameGroup = matchGroups.Groups["UsernameGroup"];

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(usernameGroup.Value))
{
    // Replace non-alphanumeric values with empty string.
    string validUsername = Regex.Replace(usernameGroup.Value, "[^a-zA-Z0-9]", string.Empty);

    // Replace the the invalid instance with the valid one.
    validInput = validInput.Replace(usernameGroup.Value, validUsername);
}

// Get the domain group from the list of matches.
var domainGroup = matchGroups.Groups["DomainGroup"];

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(domainGroup.Value))
{
    // Replace non-alphanumeric values with empty string.
    string validDomain = Regex.Replace(domainGroup.Value, "[^a-zA-Z0-9]", string.Empty);

    // Replace the the invalid instance with the valid one.
    validInput = validInput.Replace(domainGroup.Value, validDomain);
}

Console.WriteLine(validInput);
```

will output `employee12radm32@company9899.com`.